# LinuxMint 14 x64 halts during startup at: stopping samba auto-reload integration

Tags: startup, init

My Lenovo Y500 intel i7 nvidia gt 560m LinuxMint 14 x64 halts during startup at:

```
stopping samba auto-reload integration
```

No error shown. No login prompt.

I accidentally executed this in the wrong terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
sudo ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

then I tried to fix it with:

```
mv /sbin/initctl /initctl
dpkg-divert --remove /sbin/initctl
```

How can I make my system start properly again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: 
startup from live cd. Chroot to installation.

```
mv /sbin/initctl /initctl
dpkg-divert --remove /sbin/initctl
apt-get install --reinstall initctl
```